# Determine Logo link based on URL using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Situation is getting a logo on:

domain.com/special_dir/any_page

or

domain.com/special_dir/any_dir/

to use a link to [domain.com/special_dir/].

Everywhere else on [domain.com/] the logo must a link to [domain.com/]

This is what I have so far.

```
<?php
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if( $host == 'domain.com/special_dir/' ) {
    echo '<div"><a href="//domain.com/special_dir/"><img src="..."></a></div>';
  } else {
    echo '<div"><a href="//domain.com/"><img src="..."></a></div>';
}
?>
```

The logo for [domain.com/special_dir/] only works for [domain.com/special_dir/] URL, no others. I suppose the code it doing what it should, I just don't know how to make it recursive. I did search and read a lot of similar situations but none based on PHP code worked for me.

It is WordPress Multi-site setup and the "special_dir" is a regular sub-directory.

How to correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `if ($host == 'domain.com/special_dir/')` statement means the special link will be printed for `domain.com/special_dir/` only.  It excludes everything else, including `comain.com/special_dir/any_dir` and `domain.com/special_dir/any_page`.

If think you want ...

```
if (substr($host,0,22) == 'domain.com/special_dir/') { ... }
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work for me. My code was only my starting point. If it needs to be completely rewritten, I'm OK with that.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick.

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if (strpos($url, "/special_dir/") === 0) {
    echo '<div"><a href="//domain.com/special_dir/"><img src="..."></a></div>';
  } else {
    echo '<div"><a href="//domain.com/"><img src="..."></a></div>';
}
?>
```